# Laplace transform of $f(t)=\lfloor t\rfloor$

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm solving a problem but I haven't been able to move forward because it gives me discordance.

> Let $f$ defined by
> $$f(t)=n \quad t\in [n,n+1)$$
> Show
> $$F(s)=\frac{1}{s}\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-sn}$$

but when I try I get to this expression
$$F(S) = \frac{1-e^{-s}}{s}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ne^{-sn}$$
What will I be doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong. It's possible to show that your result is equal to the other one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function f can be written as
$$f(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Theta(t-n)$$
a sum of shifted step functions. This yields the desired transformation
$$F(s) = \frac{1}{s}\cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-sn}$$
Your solution is also not wrong. Notice that
$$ \frac{1-e^{-s}}{s}\cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ne^{-sn} = \frac{1}{s}\cdot (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ne^{-sn} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ne^{-s(n+1)}) $$
The last two sums can be simplifed even further by adding them componentwise
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ne^{-sn} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ne^{-s(n+1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n - (n-1))\cdot e^{-sn}$$
(substitute k = n+1 and notice that k = 1 for n = 0 in the second sum on the left side)
Therefore we arrive at the same solution
$$F(s) = \frac{1}{s}\cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-sn} = \frac{1-e^{-s}}{s}\cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ne^{-sn} $$

Comment: See the reference I just gave in a comment.